# Can't make textbox inputs work between multiple windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to set up one window that you can input variables, and it shows up in the second window.
I am working with python 3.4.3

This one doesn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
class App():
def __init__(self):
    def test():
        self.hey += self.Ventry.get()
        self.run()
    self.root = Tk()
    self.Groot = Tk()
    self.hey = 1
    self.w= Canvas(self.root, width = 700, height = 700)
    self.w.pack()
    self.Ventry = IntVar()
    self.VelBox = Entry(self.Groot, textvariable=self.Ventry)
    self.VelBox.pack()
    self.button = Button(self.Groot,command=test)
    self.button.pack()
    self.run()
    self.root.mainloop()
    self.Groot.mainloop()

def run(self):
    self.w.delete("all")
    self.w.create_text(30, 40 , text= self.hey)

myapp = App()
```

But this one does:

```
from tkinter import *
class App():
def __init__(self):
    def test():
        self.hey += self.Ventry.get()
        self.run()
    self.root = Tk()
    self.Groot = Tk()
    self.hey = 1
    self.w= Canvas(self.root, width = 700, height = 700)
    self.w.pack()
    self.Ventry = IntVar()
    self.VelBox = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.Ventry)
    self.VelBox.pack()
    self.button = Button(self.Groot,command=test)
    self.button.pack()
    self.run()

    self.root.mainloop()
    self.Groot.mainloop()
def run(self):
    self.w.delete("all")
    self.w.create_text(30, 40 , text= self.hey)

myapp = App()
```

I can't figure out why it isn't pulling the variable from a separate window at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't make root `Tk()` objects inside your app class, and don't make multiple ones. This is not the standard approach to OO `tkinter` apps. Make one root inheriting from `Tk`, then, within the app, create new windows with the `Toplevel()` widget. Check out the tutorials on [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/).

Comment: The root (no pun intended… well, maybe a little) problem here is that `self.root.mainloop()` doesn't return, and therefore the `self.Groot.mainloop()` doesn't start, until the `self.root` GUI closes down. But there's a huge bunch of undefined behavior here (as TigerhawkT3 says, you almost never want multiple roots; if you really think you do, you need to learn a whole lot of complicated stuff to use them), so even if you fix that by, say, interleaving the loops, it still may not work, or may work on one machine and not another.

Comment: To clarify: You should only ever create one instance of `Tk()`, and you should only ever call `mainloop()` exactly once. If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`

Comment: Okay thank you all, I'll have a look into it :)

Comment: Toplevel() worked, thanks guys!